# Matplotlib: make x-axis longer

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib, plot

In `Matplotlib` I need to draw a graph with points on the x-axis on each integer between `1` and `5000` and on the y-axis only in a very limited range.

`Matplotlib` automatically compacts everything to let all the data fit on a (landscape) page. In my case I would like the x-axis to be as large as possible so that all points are clearly visible. Right now there's just a thick coloured line as opposed to scattered points.

How can I do this?

(I'm saving to pdf, if that helps)

Comment: Can you post images of what you have and what you want?  I am not sure I understand your question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can always try to specify the dimensions (in inches) of the figure you are creating. Something along the following line might help:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 2))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y)
```

The `figsize` takes a tuple of width, height in inches.

Comment: if you add then `plt.tight_layout()` the subplot will get stretched to occupy as much of the figure canvas as possible, accounting for axis and ticks labels