# change width in bar chart with matplotlib before save it in file

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, charts

I created a chart using matplotlib. I am using python3.6. This is my code:

```
ev={}
for event in cumulatives:
    ev[event[0]]=event[1]
names = list(ev.keys())
values = list(ev.values())
count = len(names)
for i in range(count):
    plt.bar(i,values[i],tick_label=names[i])
plt.xticks(range(0,count),names)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('static/img/em_system_event_chart.png')
```

Here is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlvbX.png).

As you can see, the x-axis is too small. How can I make the x-axis bigger?

Answer (score 0):

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14632729/matplotlib-make-x-axis-longer).

Specify the dimensions.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 2))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y)
```

The figsize takes a tuple of width, height in inches.